# Alter border and cursor using jquery layout

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-layout

I am trying to do 2 things

1) remove the border between section (currently grey area)

2) remove area around the cursor ( you should only see '<' or '>' not dark area around it

here is my current code

http://jsfiddle.net/dan_vitch/KSuck/1/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add following to your css:

```
body > div {
    border: 0 solid white !important;
}

.ui-layout-toggler {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

The first overwrites the border definitions and the second sets the background color of the toggle to transparent.

Also see the updated [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/KSuck/2/).

=== UPDATE ===

An alternative is setting them by jquery:

```
$('body > div').css({
    border: '0 solid white'
});

$('.ui-layout-toggler').css({
    'background-color': 'transparent'
});
```

Also see the next [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/KSuck/3/).

Or shorter:

```
$('body > div').css('border', '0 solid white');
$('.ui-layout-toggler').css('background-color', 'transparent');
```

Also see the next [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/KSuck/5/).

=== UPDATE ===

Do you mean this?

```
$('.ui-layout-resizer-west').css('background-color', 'transparent');
```

Also see the next [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/KSuck/8/).

Or with css

```
.ui-layout-resizer-west {
    background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

Also see the next [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/scessor/KSuck/7/).

Comment: the only thing that's still there is the border on the west (where the toggle cursor is).